# How to send a stl file from js using ajax to php without form data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

User Imports a .stl file in js which has to be saved into database or server folder. Using javascript we are importing file from js, but since we cannot save it in our server, so im using ajax to send the file from js to php. So that from php we can save it in our folder.

Below is code in which file is being fetched, but that file is not going to php. Please help me how to send a stl file from js to php

```js
Stage.prototype.handleFile = function(file) {
  this.importingMeshName = file.name;
  this.importEnabled = false;

  var model = new Model(
    this.scene,
    this.camera,
    this.container,
    this.printout,
    this.infoBox,
    this.progressBarContainer
  );

  model.isLittleEndian = this.isLittleEndian;
  model.vertexPrecision = this.vertexPrecision;
  model.import(file, this.displayMesh.bind(this));

  var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
  jQuery.ajax
({ 
  
 
        url: 'saveinjs.php',
        type: "POST",
        data:   {user:1, postdata:form_data},
  contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
       
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
  alert(data);
    console.log(data);
    },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
  }
  
});
};
```

This is php code to fetch the file and save in our folder

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['user'])){
 echo '123';


if($_POST["file"]["name"] != '')
{
 $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];       // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript `File` api to read content in base64 format. Then in your back end code you can decrypt to get actual content. Below is the frontend code for handling the file

```js
function handleFile(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
     var data = {data: reader.result};
     // You can post data object to server in json format
     // Make Ajax request
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
     // Handle error
   };
}

var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
handleFile(file);
```

And using `base64_decode` function in php you can decode base64 string, http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: Im not getting how to save uploaded file in php,, following is my php code, because i do not have a form, so how to save a stl file in php   <?php

 $filedesc = $_POST['data'];
 $current = base64_decode($filedesc);
 $src = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $targ = "../uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($src, $targ);
?>

Comment: First you have to decode json data before decoding from base64, Below is the small code snipped for accessing post json data and decoding using base64 $postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$jsonData = json_decode($postData, true);
$fileData = $jsonData['data'];
$decodedData = base64_decode($fileData);

Comment: thank u sir, but in last step in $decodedData-> it contains file.. how to store it,,, i want to download file and keep in my server folder. plz help sir

Comment: You can use `file_put_contents` builtin php function, https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp. Once your content is in `$decodeData` variable then `file_put_contents('somefile.txt', $decodeData)`

Comment: It should work with binary file also, instead of `somefile.txt` you can use `somefile.stl`. Let me know it works or giving any error

Comment: it is saving wit the name somefile.txt or somefile.stl.. but its 0kb,, nothing is being saved in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172142/discussion-between-sriharsha-bhat-and-rashmi-sm).